# How to run eclipse .launch file in intellij new version?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I have .launch files in my project and I would like to run them in intellj.
I tried to install eclipse but I get the following erromsg:

[image]

Comment: This looks like a bug of an IntelliJ plugin that does not respect registered trademarks. Stack Overflow is to ask questions, not to report bugs.

Comment: This is because the plugin author hasn't updated their plugin since 2022 but the newest IDEA version is 2023.*. Thus the supported version range is limited.

I've created a patched version that could be installed on IDEA 2023.2 and 2023.3, however, I'm not sure if it works well:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iy3GwIN0RQ51fonM66SUF2tPocsOFI-t/view?usp=sharing 

Please contact the author of the plugin(get from https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7153-eclipser) to fix it officially.
mclovin@kukido.com